# How to pass multiple arguments when using generator comprehension?

Tags: python, arguments, list-comprehension, generator

This is a beginner question, however, I can't seem to figure it out on my own.
Can somebody please show me how to pass multiple arguments when writing a generator comprehension?

I would like to count ALL elements inside ALL tuple objects

This does half the job:

```
from collections import Counter

tup_list = [(0, 1), (0, 2), (3, 4), (3, 5), (4, 5)]

elements = Counter(x[0] for x in tup_list)

print(elements)
```

returns

```
Counter({0: 2, 3: 2, 4: 1})
```

However, the desired result would be:

```
Counter({0: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2, 1: 1, 2: 1})
```

I could achieve this by iterating through the list twice by `elements = Counter(x[0] for x in tup_list) + Counter(x[1] for x in tup_list)`, but that does not seem very practical.

I tried something like `elements = Counter(x[0], y[1] for x, y in tup_list)`, but that is incorrect syntax.

What is the correct way to write the expression with multiple arguments, please?

Comment: `Counter(item for tup in tup_list for item in tup)`? Just iterate through your `tuple`.

Comment: Thank you! That was it :) It's a double for loop, right?

Comment: Yes, it is the equivalent of a nested `for` loop. The nested portion goes to the right. `for tup in tup_list: for item in tup: yield item`